# Overlaying images using CSS

Tags: css, image, image-manipulation, overlay

I have the following images:

[image]  and [image]

and using css I need to show them on the web page as one image:

[image]

I.e. the smaller image is in the right bottom corner of the bigger image on top of it.

The size of the bigger image is not static - the image will be different every time you reload the page.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the images in `<div>`s with `display:inline-block; position: relative`. Then you can absolutely position your little badge images. For example:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" width="200" height="200">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/50/50" width="50" height="50" class="badge">
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/250/200" width="250" height="200">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/25/50" width="25" height="50" class="badge">
</div>
```

And:

```
.wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 0;
}
.badge {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

And a live version: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/sEH6L/

The `display: inline-block` and `line-height` will tightly wrap the `<div>` around the main image so that it will have the same size as the image, the `position: relative` is needed for the `position: absolute` on the badges; then you absolutely position the badge in the lower right corner of the `<div>` and you're done.

Comment: if you have no control over the contents of the images, I would also recommend this approach. My only suggestion would be that as the tick is more of a status indicator than content in its own right, replace the `img.badge` element with a `span.badge` with some assistive text inside it.

Comment: @chris or leave it as an `img` and put an `alt="..."` on it

Answer (score 0):

In your specific example, the lightbulb could be a transparent png. In which case, why not just set a `background-image` for the `<img>` tag for the lightbulb?

```
img.tick { background: url(tick.png) 100% 100% no-repeat; }
```

To get the distance between the images right, you can always add padding to the  element, too.

http://jsfiddle.net/HM7F2/

Comment: See, I don't have control over what exactly image will be instead of light bulb - it might be any png that user supplies, that's why I couldn't use the background trick in the first place.